# Keypress function not printing console.log statement and allowing illegal chars

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-devtools

Is there any reason why this would not print the desired console.log statement to my console & allow illegal characters (i.e., any characters that are not the numbers 0-9) to be logged to the console? Right now, I'm getting every button press logged to the console, even the ones I don't want, and not the console.log statement I do want. The behaviour of this code has been so inconsistent I have questioned whether or not there was something wrong with my IDE or Chrome. Note, I have also used keyup and have had the same problems.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  // declare empty infix string
  // declare empty infix string
  let infix = "";
  // get input from user on key press (separate function)
  (function getInput() {
      $(window).keypress(function(e) {
          if("1234567890".includes(e.key)) {
              infix += e.key;
              console.log("infix" + e.key);
          }
      });
  })();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!DOCTYPE>
    
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
            <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
            <style>
                body {
                    background-color: #000000;
                }
    
                .container {
                    width: 420px;
                    height: 500px;
                    background-color: #c8c8c8;
                }
    
                .btn-group {
                    margin: 5px;
                }
    
                .btn.btn-primary {
                    width: 59px;
                    height: 34px;
                }
    
                #title {
                    background-color: #c8c8c8;
                }
    
                #screen {
                    width: 300px;
                    height: 35px;
                    border-radius: 15px;
                    margin: 5px 0px 10px 0px;
                    /* take care of cursor's right alignment */
                    color:black;
                    font-size: 15px;
                    text-align:right;
                    padding-bottom:0;
                    font-family: helvetica;
                }
            </style>
            <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                // declare empty infix string
                // declare empty infix string
                let infix = "";
                // get input from user on key press (separate function)
                    (function getInput() {
                        $(window).on("keyup", function(e) {
                            if("1234567890".includes(e.key)) {
                                infix += e.key;
                                console.log("infix" + e.key);
                            }
                        });
                    })();
            // It's IIFE, not jQuery
                // display input on screen (separate function)
    
                // assign input to string (separate function)
    
                // get operator from user and add to infix
    
                // if equals pressed
    
                    // eval infix string
    
                // if clear pressed
    
                    // reset to empty string
    
                    // display blank screen
    
            });
            </script>
    
            <title>Calculator</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row text-center">
                    <div id="title" class="col-md-12 text-center">
                        <h4>Business Analyst</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-12 body text-center">
                        <input id="screen" type=text>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-12 body text-center">
                        <div class="btn-group">
                            <button id="enter" class="btn btn-primary">Enter</button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="btn-group">
                            <button id="compute" class="btn btn-primary">CPT</button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="btn-group">
                            <button id="clear-cash-flow" class="btn btn-primary">CCF</button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="btn-group">
                            <button id="analyst-mode" class="btn btn-primary">AM</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-12 body text-center">
                        <div class="btn-group">
                            <button id="fut-val" class="btn btn-primary">FV</button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="btn-group">
                            <button id="cash-flow" class="btn btn-primary">CF</button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="btn-group">
                            <button id="net-pv" class="btn btn-primary">NPV</button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="btn-group">
                            <button id="irr" class="btn btn-primary">IRR</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-12 body text-center">
                        <div class="btn-group">
                            <button id="period" class="btn btn-primary">N</button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="btn-group">
                            <button id="int-rate" class="btn btn-primary">I|Y</button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="btn-group">
                            <button id="pres-val" class="btn btn-primary">PV</button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="btn-group">
                            <button id="payment" class="btn btn-primary">PMT</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-12 body text-center">
                        <div class="btn-group">
                            <button id="clear" class="btn btn-primary">C</button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="btn-group">
                            <button id="percent" class="btn btn-primary">%</button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="btn-group">
                            <button id="lftparen" class="btn btn-primary">(</button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="btn-group">
                            <button id="rtparen" class="btn btn-primary">)</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-12 body text-center">
                        <div class="btn-group">
                            <button id="seven" class="btn btn-primary">7</button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="btn-group">
                            <button id="eight" class="btn btn-primary">8</button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="btn-group">
                            <button id="nine" class="btn btn-primary">9</button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="btn-group">
                            <button id="division" class="btn btn-primary"><span>&#247;</span></button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-12 body text-center">
                        <div class="btn-group">
                            <button id="four" class="btn btn-primary">4</button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="btn-group">
                            <button id="five" class="btn btn-primary">5</button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="btn-group">
                            <button id="six" class="btn btn-primary">6</button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="btn-group">
                            <button id="division" class="btn btn-primary">X</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-12 body text-center">
                        <div class="btn-group">
                            <button id="one" class="btn btn-primary">1</button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="btn-group">
                            <button id="two" class="btn btn-primary">2</button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="btn-group">
                            <button id="three" class="btn btn-primary">3</button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="btn-group">
                            <button id="subtraction" class="btn btn-primary">-</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-12 body text-center">
                        <div class="btn-group">
                            <button id="zero" class="btn btn-primary">0</button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="btn-group">
                            <button id="decimal" class="btn btn-primary">.</button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="btn-group">
                            <button id="equal" class="btn btn-primary">=</button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="btn-group">
                            <button id="addition" class="btn btn-primary">+</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Well, this code seems to work fine in Firefox

Comment: Works fine in Chrome too. Have you checked compability of includes https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes ?

Comment: Your code works in chrome just fine. Perhaps it is not with this snippet but with other code on your page? Are there other keypress listeners perhaps?

Comment: Works fine as a fiddle as well: https://jsfiddle.net/zpLj89gh/

Comment: Is there any possibility that my chrome console settings could be off. I'm preserving logs, Logging XMLHttp, and Showing Timestamps. I have not checked the above docs. I was unaware of them.

Comment: @Ryan what does the console show when you run the fiddle in my previous comment? Nothing at all?

Comment: @Tomanow There was, it was commented out, it was so small I deleted it and re-ran. Still, same issues. <ascii shrug>

Comment: @rolfv1 The fiddle works beautifully. Exactly as expected.

Comment: There is, obviously, HTML on the page, as well as the standard bootstrap links.

Comment: when you run precisely your page with the issue in another browser, do you still have issues?

Comment: @Ryan as the fiddle works perfectly, there is something else in your code that is counteracting the function definitions that you have posted. So check your code, and also see if it works without the bootstrap links.

Comment: No go in Safari.

Comment: I'm editing to put the entire page up.

Comment: @rolfv1 I assume that is my only option. Trouble is, the markup I have relies *heavily* on bootstrap. But, if it's abandon bootstrap, then I have few other options.

Comment: @Ryan the entire page still works fine for me, also in a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zpLj89gh/1/ (and no, that's definitely not how you would normally use a fiddle:) )

Comment: @rolfv1 I appreciate you checking it out so thoroughly. I'll check with Cloud9 to see if they have any announcements that suggest their IDE is having issues.